# How to split float in PHP?

Tags: php, math, numbers

Let's say we have 12.054 and I want to split it to three variables like `$whole_number=12` `$numerator=54` and `$denominator=1000`. Could you help me?

Comment: What's the purpose of this? How do you want to use them?

Comment: You probably would never actually *have* such a number because 54/100 is not a sum of powers of two. So at best you could put in an arbitrary round-off and get some approximate answer. Or more simply put, if `$x = 1.0/3.0;`, do you want 33/100, 333/1000 or 3333/10000?

Comment: @Kerrek SB I enter number manually through html form

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6619377/2943403

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A straight-forward approach - not very academic, but it works for PHP ;-):

```
$float        = 12.054;
$parts        = explode('.', (string)$float);
$whole_number = $parts[0];
$numerator    = trim($parts[1], '0');
$denominator  = pow(10, strlen(rtrim($parts[1], '0')));
```

Some more work might be needed to ensure that edge case work too (trailing `0`s, no decimal part at all, etc.).

Comment: If you might reach the integer limit, then just remove the `(int)`-cast, which is not really necessary. `$whole_number` and `$numerator` will be strings then.

Comment: If I don't use int then $numerator will be 054, how could I remove those zero(s)?

Comment: Edited the example - now using `trim()` to remove training and leading `0`s from the `$numerator`

Comment: would it be possible to get from $float = 1/3 $numerator = 1 and $denominator = 3 (of coure not with this code) or no because of precision?

Answer (score 4):

Here is something to get you started , based on simple type conversions.

http://codepad.org/7ExBhTMS

However, there are many cases to consider like :

1. Preceding/trailing zeros.  12.0540   ( is 540/10000 or 54/1000 for you )
2. Handling decimals with no fractional part eg. 12.00 .

   ```
   $val = 12.054;
   print_r(splitter($val));

   function splitter($val)
   {
     $str = (string) $val ;
     $splitted = explode(".",$str);
     $whole = (integer)$splitted[0] ;
     $num = (integer) $splitted[1];
     $den = (integer)  pow(10,strlen($splitted[1]));
     return array('whole' => $whole, 'num' => $num,'den' => $den);
   }



   ?>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
<?
$no = 12.54;
$arr = explode(".", $no);

$full_no = $arr[0].$arr[1];

for($i = 0; $i < strlen($arr[1]); $i++) $denominator = $denominator."0";

$denominator = "1".$denominator;

$numerator = $full_no % $denominator;

$whole_no = $full_no / $denominator;

echo "Denominator = ". $denominator ."<br>";

echo "Numerator = ". $numerator ."<br>";

echo "Whole No = ". (int)$whole_no ."<br>";
?>
```

Output :

```
Denominator = 100
Numerator = 54
Whole No = 12
```

Output for 12.054 :

```
Denominator = 1000
Numerator = 54
Whole No = 12
```

I hope this will help you..