# How to get whole and decimal part of a number?

Tags: php, math

Given, say, 1.25 - how do I get "1" and ."25" parts of this number?

I need to check if the decimal part is .0, .25, .5, or .75.

Comment: Will a simple explode work? $splitDec = explode(".", $decimal); $splitDec[0] will now by the 1 and splitDec[1] will now be 25 from your example.

Comment: @Matt `split()` has been deprecated.

Comment: @alex yea, forgot. Was thinking javascript. changed to explode.

Comment: @Matt, split has been deprecated as of PHP 5.3 and actually takes a regex as its arg, whereas explode takes a string. explode() is preferred in this case.

Comment: Be aware that `explode(".",1.10);` wil give 1 and 1, not 1 and 10

Answer (score 222, accepted):

```
$n = 1.25;
$whole = floor($n);      // 1
$fraction = $n - $whole; // .25
```

Then compare against 1/4, 1/2, 3/4, etc.

---

In cases of negative numbers, use this:

```
function NumberBreakdown($number, $returnUnsigned = false)
{
  $negative = 1;
  if ($number < 0)
  {
    $negative = -1;
    $number *= -1;
  }

  if ($returnUnsigned){
    return array(
      floor($number),
      ($number - floor($number))
    );
  }

  return array(
    floor($number) * $negative,
    ($number - floor($number)) * $negative
  );
}
```

The `$returnUnsigned` stops it from making **-1.25** in to **-1** & **-0.25**

Comment: As a side, `intval()` or simple casting as `(int)` might be more performant than `floor()`

Comment: How does floor account for negatives?

Comment: @LanceH: It doesn't, but you can make it handle it pretty easily with a negative flag.

Comment: This answer is actually inaccurate unless you add a round(). Sounds dumb, I know, but it has to do with low-level floating point number arithmetic.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726721/php-math-precision

Comment: Try with 510.9, returns 0.89. But can't tell why.

Comment: Try it for 4.01 it fails
  
$n = 4.01;
$whole = floor($n);      // 4
$fraction = $n - $whole; // should be .01
echo $fraction;

Answer (score 41):

This code will split it up for you:

```
list($whole, $decimal) = explode('.', $your_number);
```

where $whole is the whole number and $decimal will have the digits after the decimal point.

Comment: Be aware that `explode(".",1.10);` wil give 1 and 1, not 1 and 10

Comment: This breaks and throws warning about undefined index, if number is integer or does not contain decimal part.

Comment: This assumes that the number is not going to end up being represented in scientific notation when cast to string.  If it's a really really huge or really really tiny number then this won't be the case and this method will break.

Comment: It doesn't work when your number is : $value = 10000000000000.00011111;

Comment: this works very well for numbers in outline form (``x.y``) - thanks

Answer (score 36):

The floor() method doesn't work for negative numbers.  This works every time:

```
$num = 5.7;
$whole = (int) $num;  // 5
$frac  = $num - $whole;  // .7
```

...also works for negatives (same code, different number):

```
$num = -5.7;
$whole = (int) $num;  // -5
$frac  = $num - $whole;  // -.7
```

Comment: when the number is something like  $value = 10000000000000.00011111; it does not work too

Comment: @HamidNaghipour It does as long as your processor can handle enough bits. It's a limitation of the computer handling it as a numeric value instead of a string.

Answer (score 23):

Just to be different :)

```
list($whole, $decimal) = sscanf(1.5, '%d.%d');
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/myLIEIsr).

As an added benefit, it will only split where both sides consist of digits.

Comment: This one does not break if number does not contain decimal part. Great!

Comment: Nice that this outputs two integers; rather than an int and a float.

Comment: This assumes that the number is not going to end up being represented in scientific notation when cast to string. If it's a really really huge or really really tiny number then this won't be the case and this method will break.

Comment: And this one dose not work when the number is like this: $value = 10000000000000.00011111;

Comment: sscanf() first argument should be a string https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.sscanf.php don't forget to cast your float to a string

Comment: `sscanf()` performs greedy matching and variables can be assigned within the function call (`list()` is not required) https://stackoverflow.com/a/69039147/2943403

Answer (score 18):

a short way (use floor and fmod)

```
$var = "1.25";
$whole = floor($var);     // 1
$decimal = fmod($var, 1); //0.25
```

then compare $decimal to 0, .25, .5, or .75

Comment: I accept this answer! It's close to C#'s `(a % 1)` AND it handles negative numbers well.

Answer (score 8):

Cast it as an int and subtract

```
$integer = (int)$your_number;
$decimal = $your_number - $integer;
```

Or just to get the decimal for comparison

```
$decimal = $your_number - (int)$your_number
```

Answer (score 5):

There's a fmod function too, that can be used :
fmod($my_var, 1)
will return the same result, but sometime with a small round error.

Answer (score 5):

**PHP 5.4+**

```
$n = 12.343;
intval($n); // 12
explode('.', number_format($n, 1))[1]; // 3
explode('.', number_format($n, 2))[1]; // 34
explode('.', number_format($n, 3))[1]; // 343
explode('.', number_format($n, 4))[1]; // 3430
```

Answer (score 5):

Just a new simple solution, for those of you who want **to get the Integer part and Decimal part splitted as two integer separated values**:

**5.25** -> Int part: **5**; Decimal part: **25**

```
$num = 5.25;
$int_part = intval($num);
$dec_part = $num * 100 % 100;
```

This way is not involving string based functions, and is preventing accuracy problems which may arise in other math operations (such as having 0.49999999999999 instead of 0.5).

Haven't tested thoroughly with extreme values, but it works fine for me for price calculations.

But, watch out! Now from **-5.25** you get: Integer part: **-5**; Decimal part: **-25**

In case you want to get always positive numbers, simply add `abs()` before the calculations:

```
$num = -5.25;
$num = abs($num);
$int_part = intval($num);
$dec_part = $num * 100 % 100;
```

Finally, bonus snippet for printing prices with 2 decimals:

```
$message = sprintf("Your price: %d.%02d Eur", $int_part, $dec_part);
```

...so that you avoid getting 5.5 instead of 5.05. ;)

Comment: These techniques too rigidly require two decimal places in the input.

Comment: The code did not work with '154.45' it returns 44.

Answer (score 2):

This is the way which I use:

```
$float = 4.3;    

$dec = ltrim(($float - floor($float)),"0."); // result .3
```

Answer (score 1):

Brad Christie's method is essentially correct but it can be written more concisely.

```
function extractFraction ($value) 
{
    $fraction   = $value - floor ($value);
    if ($value < 0)
    {
        $fraction *= -1;
    }

    return $fraction;
}
```

This is equivalent to his method but shorter and hopefully easier to understand as a result.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a hard time finding a way to actually separate the dollar amount and the amount after the decimal. I think I figured it out mostly and thought to share if any of yall were having trouble

So basically...

if price is 1234.44... whole would be 1234 and decimal would be 44 or

if price is 1234.01... whole would be 1234 and decimal would be 01 or

if price is 1234.10... whole would be 1234 and decimal would be 10

and so forth

```
$price = 1234.44;

$whole = intval($price); // 1234
$decimal1 = $price - $whole; // 0.44000000000005 uh oh! that's why it needs... (see next line)
$decimal2 = round($decimal1, 2); // 0.44 this will round off the excess numbers
$decimal = substr($decimal2, 2); // 44 this removed the first 2 characters

if ($decimal == 1) { $decimal = 10; } // Michel's warning is correct...
if ($decimal == 2) { $decimal = 20; } // if the price is 1234.10... the decimal will be 1...
if ($decimal == 3) { $decimal = 30; } // so make sure to add these rules too
if ($decimal == 4) { $decimal = 40; }
if ($decimal == 5) { $decimal = 50; }
if ($decimal == 6) { $decimal = 60; }
if ($decimal == 7) { $decimal = 70; }
if ($decimal == 8) { $decimal = 80; }
if ($decimal == 9) { $decimal = 90; }

echo 'The dollar amount is ' . $whole . ' and the decimal amount is ' . $decimal;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$x = 1.24

$result = $x - floor($x);

echo $result; // .24
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can count on it always having 2 decimal places, you can just use a string operation:

```
$decimal = 1.25;
substr($decimal,-2);  // returns "25" as a string
```

No idea of performance but for my simple case this was much better...

Comment: Note: if you do this, you should at least use round($decimal, 2); first to ensure you only have two digits as decimal. But you can not use this if you want to have correct math or handle money.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the extra float decimal (i.e. 50.85 - 50 give 0.850000000852), in my case I just need 2 decimals for money cents.

```
$n = 50.85;
$whole = intval($n);
$fraction = $n * 100 % 100;
```

Comment: This answer is not suitable for floats with more or less than 2 decimal places. https://3v4l.org/An9gO

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way... it's easier like this

```
$var = "0.98";

$decimal = strrchr($var,".");

$whole_no = $var-$decimal;

echo $whole_no;

echo str_replace(".", "", $decimal);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use something like this:

```
preg_match("/([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)/", $number, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the two halves to be explicitly type cast, then `sscanf()` is a great call.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/O8LQG))

```
var_dump(sscanf(1.25, '%d%f'));
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  float(0.25)
}
```

---

Or you can assign the two variables individually:

```
sscanf(1.25, '%d%f', $int, $float);
var_dump($int);
var_dump($float);
```

---

Casting the decimal portion as a float is particularly useful when, say, converting decimal expression of hours to hours and minutes. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VLbfZ))

```
$decimalTimes = [
    6,
    7.2,
    8.78,
];

foreach ($decimalTimes as $decimalTime) {
    sscanf($decimalTime, '%d%f', $hours, $minutes);
    printf('%dh%02dm', $hours, round($minutes * 60));
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
6h00m
7h12m
8h47m  // if round() was not used, this would be 8h46m
```

Answer (score -1):

Not seen a simple modulus here...

```
$number         = 1.25;
$wholeAsFloat   = floor($number);   // 1.00
$wholeAsInt     = intval($number);  // 1
$decimal        = $number % 1;      // 0.25
```

In this case getting both `$wholeAs?` and `$decimal` don't depend on the other. (You can just take 1 of the 3 outputs independently.) I've shown `$wholeAsFloat` and `$wholeAsInt` because [`floor()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) returns a float type number even though the number it returns will always be whole. (This is important if you're passing the result into a type-hinted function parameter.)

I wanted this to split a floating point number of hours/minutes, e.g. 96.25, into hours and minutes separately for a [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) instance as 96 hours 15 minutes. I did this as follows:

```
$interval = new \DateInterval(sprintf("PT%dH%dM", intval($hours), (($hours % 1) * 60)));
```

I didn't care about seconds in my case.

Answer (score -3):

```
val = -3.1234

fraction = abs(val - as.integer(val) )
```

Comment: Hi, do add a bit of explanation along with the code as it helps to understand your code. Code only answers are frowned upon.