# Padding zeroes to Price

Tags: php

```
$price = 10.00;
list($dollars, $cents) = explode('.', $price);
echo $dollars . '.' . $cents;
```

... almost works except that the zeros are omitted. `10.00` becomes `10` and `10.10` becomes `10.1`

I see there's a padding function for strings, but anything for numbers or floats?

How do I fix this?

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619377/how-to-get-whole-and-decimal-part-of-a-number explanation will help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Sprintf

```
$digit = sprintf("%02d", $digit);
```

For more information, refer to the documentation of [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf).

Comment: It is incorrect. Because: printf("%02d", 10.00); is 10 instead 10.00

Answer (score 8):

You can use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
echo number_format($price, 2); // Would print 10.00
```

You can specify a separator for the decimal point and another one for the thousands:

```
echo number_format(1234.56, 2, ',', ' '); // Would print 1 234,56
```

Answer (score 1):

number_format is what you want: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 1):

Though i would recommend [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php), you could use

```
sprintf('%02.2f', $price)
```

if you want to rely on string functions.